# Css - mantain two tables with the same width

Tags: html, css

I have two html tables, one above the other, both with width 100%, something like

```
<div>
    <table>table content...</table>
    <table>table content...</table>
<div>
```

When the page is large enough the two table have the same width. But when I restrict the page, at a certain point, one of the two tables stops shrinking and the other continues, causing the fact that the two tables don't have the same width anymore.

You can see it in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jr3dqdx0/).

Is there a way with pure css to tell the two tables to maintain the same width? What would be nice is that when the first table stops to shrink, the second stops as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following to the CSS code:

```
.t-scroller {
    display:inline-block;
    clear:both;
}
```

See here in **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jr3dqdx0/5/)**.

**Note:** This one is on the DIV level and I don't know whether you can afford that. But this should do the trick...

Try this out. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Add `table-layout: fixed;` to the table.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jr3dqdx0/2/).

Comment: thanks, but this causes the content of the cells to go out of the cell itself

Comment: Yes, at a certained point, the cells are to small to fit its contents... That's why they both have different widths in your original code. You could fix that by giving the table a minimum width with `min-width: 600px`. You'll need to try a which point it breaks, and set that as the min-width.

Answer (score 0):

you can also assigned a `minimum-width` to the tables, that way both tables CANNOT be smaller than a certain size. So you can assign to the size of when the top table stops shrinking.

The `table-layout: fixed;` works, but the tables both keep shrinking until you can't see the text in each of the cells, the minimum width will keep the table cells readable

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jr3dqdx0/3/)

in the fiddle I have updated your table class:

```
.table {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 550px; //added this min-width property
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: but with the `minimum-width` solution, I don't know when the first table will stop shrinking

Comment: well.. thats why you kind of test, i tried 400px, it was too small, so I went up to 500, and finally 550 was good. I'm not sure if you have many options here

Comment: your problem is that one table has 3 columns and the other has 2, thats why the top table stops shrinking first I think